# asdf commands not working even though it's installed

Tags: asdf-vm

Does anyone have much experience setting up asdf with zsh? I'm installing it via git. It appears to be installed as typing "asdf" in terminal returns a list of asdf commands, however, if I go to use one of those commands like "asdf version" or "asdf plugin list-all" it returns:

`Unknown command: 'asdf version'`

`No plugin named update`

I think it may be an issue with the path. Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I use asdf with zsh and haven't had encountered any issues. It sounds like you are having an issue with your path. It seems like completions are loaded into your shell but the actual `asdf` command is not on your `$PATH`. In my `~/.zshrc` I have this:

```
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
```

You'll need to share more info about how you installed asdf for me to comment on what has gone wrong with your installation.

Comment: I see that this works, but I don't quite understand what is happening here. What is this actually doing?

Answer (score 1):

"oh-my-zsh" plugin and `export PATH=/PATH_TO_ASDF:$PATH` yielded no results. Was able to fix by installing via homebrew.

Instructions here:
https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf?id=install

Comment: No, they are not there

Answer (score 1):

Mine was solved after spotting the directions after using brew install asdf. I did a reinstall and it said:

`add . /usr/local/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh to ~/.zshrc`.